# populating dropdwon list on change

Tags: jquery

I write the code below and it works fine it also bring the data from the table but it does not displayed in the a subsequent drop down
Here is my code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/vendor_master.aspx")%>'
    function PopulateStates() {
        if ($('#<%=ddl_state.ClientID%>').val() == "0") {
            $('#<%=ddl_city.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        }
        else {
            $('#<%=ddl_city.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: pageUrl + '/PopulateCities',
                data: '{stateID: ' + $('#<%=ddl_state.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnCountriesPopulated,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function OnCountriesPopulated(response) {
        PopulateControl(response.d, $("#<%=ddl_city.ClientID %>"));
    }
</script>
```

I got the following error in a firebug

```
ReferenceError: PopulateControl is not defined
    PopulateControl(response.d, $('#ddl_city'));
```

I remove the quotes but it not working for me 
please suggest me to solve the bug thanks in advance

Comment: What is PopulateControl

Comment: I just copy paste the code and modify it from  this link  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDownList-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: hello friend now i am getting an error as Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function PopulateControl(list, control) {
        if (list.length > 0) {
            control.removeAttr("disabled");
            control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            $.each(list, function () {
                control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
        else {
            control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
        }
    }
</script>
```